# Querying all records from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building some kind system for student exams. There are two tables - one that contains
questions and another that contains student id and their answers.

Table Questions

```
+-------------+------------+  
| IdQuestion  | QuestionTXT|  
+-------------+------------+  
| 1           | Q1?        |  
+-------------+------------+
| 2           | Q2?        |  
+-------------+------------+    
| 3           | Q3?        |  
+-------------+------------+ 
| 4           | Q4?        |  
+-------------+------------+ 

Table Answers:
+-------------+------------+------------+  
| StudentID   | IdQuestion | Answer     |
+-------------+------------+------------+  
| A           | 1          |   Y        |
+-------------+------------+------------+    
| A           | 2          |   N        |
+-------------+------------+------------+    
| A           | 3          |   Y        |
+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Now I have to get what the student answered and which question are not answered.

Here is a query that fetches what the student answered, on which questions:

```
SELECT `answ`.`StudentID`
`questions`.`IdQuestion`, `questions`.`QuestionText`, `answ`.`Odgovor` 
FROM `questions` 
LEFT JOIN `answ` ON `answ`.`IdQuestion` = `questions`.`IdQuestions` 
WHERE `answ`.`StudentID` = 'A'
```

But this query lists only questions that have answers (question with id 4 is missing). I need to show question that are not answered. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to the questions which are answered and not answered also then move your where condition in on clause

```
SELECT 
`a`.`StudentID`,
`q`.`IdQuestion`, 
`q`.`QuestionTXT`, 
`a`.`Answer` 
FROM `questions`  q
LEFT JOIN `answ` a
 ON `a`.`IdQuestion` = `q`.`IdQuestion` 
AND `a`.`StudentID` = 'A'
```

Where clause filter outs the records from the result set produced by join ,so using your condition in on clause will only filter the record from a table you are joining with it will not filter whole result set ,so the question no. 4 is not answered yet but it will returned in the end result set but with a null row from answers table

### [`See Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca47c0/6)